# Are User UUIDs re-used after deletion? (Firebase Authentication)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently in the process of implementing deleting users from my app, however some of their data will remain stored. Their data is uniquely identified by their User UUID in Firebase Authentication, and so I was wondering whether after a user is deleted from Firebase Authentication, can another user claim their User UUID in the future?

I ask because if a new user in the future could claim their User UUID, they would be associated with data that's actually not supposed to be associated with them (since the data is identified by the User UUID).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified on the official firebase documentation, each user has a Unique ID; this is a per registration identifier and unique for every user. If they remove their account, that ID won't be used again.
You can be sure that the user data will not get overwritten.
Remember to write strong Security Rules for your Firestore Database so your users' data can only be accessible by them.

[Users Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users)
[Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules)